# Why doesn't PDB seem to support help() on all objects like the normal Python interpreter?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

It seems like running "help(object)" in PDB doesn't really work, while in the regular interpreter it seems to work just fine most of the time. It makes debugging, especially in new projects, a bit annoying - is there any way to fix this?

```
(Pdb) help(int)
*** No help on (int)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `help...` in pdb, it invokes pdb's own builtin `help` command, which provides help regarding using pdb.

For the `help` you're looking for, you can bypass pdb's builtins using the `!` prefix:

```
(Pdb) !help(int)

Help on class int in module __builtin__:

class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> int or long
 |  int(x, base=10) -> int or long
 ...


(Pdb) help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pp       run      unt   
a      c          continue  exit    l     q        s        until 
alias  cl         d         h       list  quit     step     up    
args   clear      debug     help    n     r        tbreak   w     
b      commands   disable   ignore  next  restart  u        whatis
break  condition  down      j       p     return   unalias  where 

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

Undocumented commands:
======================
retval  rv
```

Comment: Been using PDB for years. Can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you!